# Access Singleton via Named pipe creates second singleton. Events not fired on host side

Tags: c#, events, singleton, ipc, named-pipes

I have two processes and the second process needs to have access to a singleton in the first process. So I wrote a server that should help sharing the instance.

Something is wrong though, it seems like the client gets its own version of the singleton rather than the original instance.

The minimal example comes in two projects. Here is the client:

`Program`

```
using IPCServer;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace IPCEventTest
{
    class IPCClient
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process ipcserver = Process.Start("IPCServer.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Main Start Connect");
            Module module = Connect("WellKnownName"); //this name is used by the host
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Main End Connect");
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Main Start Raise");
            module.RaiseEvent(); //raise event should raise within the server process
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Main End Raise");
            while (true) ;
        }
        public static Module Connect(string id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Connect");
            ChannelFactory<IModuleServer> pipeFactory =
                  new ChannelFactory<IModuleServer>(
                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                    new EndpointAddress($"net.pipe://localhost/{id}")
                    );
            IModuleServer serverProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            Module ret = serverProxy.GetModule();
            Console.WriteLine("End Connect");
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

The following files set up the Host:

`Program`

```
using System;

namespace IPCServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static HOST host;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            host = new HOST("WellKnownName");
            Module.Instance.myevent += Instance_myevent;
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Server Subscribed to {Module.Instance.id}");
            while (true) ;
        }

        private static void Instance_myevent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Server Event Fired from {(sender as Module).id}");
        }
    }
}
```

`Module`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace IPCServer
{
    public class Module
    {
        public static Module Instance { get; } = new Module();
        public event EventHandler myevent = delegate { };
        public string id;

        private Module()
        {
            var guid4 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Take(4);
            id = new String(guid4.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"Module Constructor {id}");
            myevent += Module_myevent;
        }

        private void Module_myevent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Module Listener {(sender as Module).id}");
        }

        public void RaiseEvent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Module Start Raise {id}");
            myevent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine($"Module End Raise {id}");
        }
    }
}
```

`Host`

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace IPCServer
{
    internal class HOST
    {
        ServiceHost host;

        internal HOST(string id)
        {
            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ModuleServer), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") });
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IModuleServer), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), id);
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Host Opened");
        }

        ~HOST()
        {
            if (host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                host.Close();
            }
            host = null;
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} Host Destructed");
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IModuleServer
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Module GetModule();
    }

    public class ModuleServer : IModuleServer
    {
        public Module GetModule()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} ModuleServer start GetModule");
            Module ret = Module.Instance;
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()} ModuleServer end GetModule");
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

The example runs and here is the output on my system:

[image: example output]

Why am i not getting my Singleton from the server process.
Why is my event not raised in the server.

Edit: The Server opens the host and also subscribes to the singleton. After the client connects it raises the event via member function. Event has two subscribers, one in the constructor and one on the server side. only the Module internal subscription is handled - there is no eventhandling on the server side - no event is fired on the server side. The module listener is triggered but not inside the host process. This event is handled on the client side.

Comment: Which events not being raised (i looked at this a few times)

Comment: @BugFinder I edited to clarify this point - you are right, the output lists the listener handling an event. but that is not the host subscription and also this is not within the host process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am i not getting my Singleton from the server process

Named pipes use Serialization to pass the object from server to client. That means that the client side have to re-run the constructor and copy existing properties.
`public string id;` is a field so it won't be 'copied' so the random value set by the constructor is left. That's why you have different Ids for the "same" object.

To solve this, you can change this to :

```
[DataContract]
public class Module
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id {get; set;}

}
```

> Why is my event not raised in the server.

This is not how WCF named pipes works as you just have a duplicate version a  client side. I suggest you to read about [Duplex Channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms731184(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks - is suspected the answer may be that i am totally wrong about named pipes.